# declaring a string in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I have this assembly code that computes some prime numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char format[] = "%d\t";

    _asm{
        mov ebx, 1000
        mov ecx, 1
        jmp start_while1
incrementare1:
        add ecx, 1
start_while1:
        cmp ecx, ebx
        jge end_while1
        mov edi, 2
        mov esi, 0
        jmp start_while2
incrementare2:
        add edi, 1
start_while2:
        cmp edi, ecx
        jge end_while2
        mov eax, ecx
        xor edx, edx
        div edi
        test edx, edx
        jnz incrementare2
        mov esi, 1
end_while2:
        test esi, esi
        jnz incrementare1
        push ecx
        lea ecx, format
        push ecx
        call printf
        pop ecx
        pop ecx
        jmp incrementare1
end_while1:
        nop
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine but I would like to also declare the 'format' string in asm, not in C code. I have tried adding something like `format db "%d\t", 0` but it didn't work.

Comment: How about making a string in C and seeing what asm the compiler generates?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396(v=vs.80).aspx if you're using Visual C++.

Comment: What about something like this: `sub    $0x04,%esp`

Comment: I have just barely scratched the surface of C, so this may be a naive way of doing this, but can't you allocate enough memory for the string in asm and then assign each character, following with a `null` to terminate the string?

Comment: @Ryan Amos yes I could do that but I'm looking for something more.. clean...

Comment: What does “it didn't work” mean? The compiler reported an error? The program compiled, but it crashed at run time? It did not crash but printed incorrect output?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil i was getting the following error: Error 1 error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'db'

Comment: @IonutHulub: You need to put a colon after “format” to tell the assembler it is a label, rather than an opcode or directive. I entered an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define objects inside the `_asm` block with those directives. The C declaration is allocating space on the stack for you so if you want to do something like that inside the `_asm` block you need to manipulate the stack pointer and initialize the memory yourself:

```
sub esp, 4
mov [esp], '%'
mov [esp + 1], 'd'
mov [esp + 2], '\t'
mov [esp + 3], '\0'
...
push ecx
push esp + 4
call printf
```

Note this is one way. Not necessarily the best way. The best way being let C do your memory management for you.

Comment: That does of course get annoyingly boring if you need to write a little more than a few characters... But then of course, using assembler code to call printf isn't exactly the best use of time, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails there's always the ugly way:

```
format_minus_1:
mov ecx,0x00096425  ; '%', 'd', '\t', '\0' in little-endian format
lea ecx,format_minus_1 + 1  ; skip past the "mov ecx" opcode
push ecx
call printf
```

Comment: I +1'ed this. Really smart hack but it won't work if you need more then 3 characters.